# How to use datum of list in android

Tags: android, list

In my application I want use this **library** : https://github.com/adroitandroid/ChipCloud

**My data is :**

```
"mostlyMatchedKeywordsText": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
    ]
```

I create this data such as below in **model** :

```
@SerializedName("mostlyMatchedKeywordsText")
@Expose
private String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsText = null;

public String[] getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText() {
    return mostlyMatchedKeywordsText;
}

public void setMostlyMatchedKeywordsText(String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsText) {
    this.mostlyMatchedKeywordsText = mostlyMatchedKeywordsText;
}
```

And write below codes for set into **chip view** :

```
String[] chipCloudList;
chipCloudList = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
                fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChips(chipCloudList);
                fullSearchMini_chipCloud.setChipListener(new ChipListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void chipSelected(int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(FullSearchMini.this, "" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void chipDeselected(int i) {

                    }
                });
```

I want when click on this chips, show data name instance of position.
**For example :** Show item1 instance of 0 .

How can I it? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your `chipCloudListchipCloudList` variable as final and access from inside on click

Ex:

```
final String[] chipCloudListchipCloudList = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
fullSearchMini_chipCloud.addChips(chipCloudList);
fullSearchMini_chipCloud.setChipListener(new ChipListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void chipSelected(int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(FullSearchMini.this, "" + chipCloudListchipCloudList[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void chipDeselected(int i) {

                    }
                });
```